# Tangent bundle of a sphere $T\mathbb S^n$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb S^n \times \mathbb S^n - \Delta$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, spheres, diffeomorphism, tangent-bundle

Let $\mathbb S^n$ denote the $n$-sphere, which is the smooth manifold consisting of all points in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ with Euclidean norm one. Recall that the tangent bundle of $\mathbb S^n$, denoted $T \mathbb S^n$, is a $2n$-dimensional smooth manifold. Let $\Delta \subseteq \mathbb S^n \times \mathbb S^n$ denote the diagonal $\Delta := \{(x,x) : x \in \mathbb S^n\}$. By Hausdorffness, $\Delta$ is closed, so $\mathbb S^n \times \mathbb S^n - \Delta$ is an open subset of $\mathbb S^n \times \mathbb S^n$.

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908137/tangent-bundle-of-the-2-sphere) about the tangent bundle of the $n$-sphere, (I believe) one of the answers claims that we have a diffeomorphism $$T\mathbb S^n \cong \mathbb S^n \times \mathbb S^n - \Delta.$$

How can we see that this is true? What is an explicit diffeomorphism?

Comment: Do you understand how stereographic projection gives a diffeomorphism between a punctured sphere and euclidean space of the same dimension?

Comment: Can you prove this for $n=1$?

Comment: @SammyBlack Yes I am familiar with stereographic projection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We must be very explicit to prove it.

1. We have
   $$S^n \times S^n \setminus \Delta = \bigcup_{p \in S^n} \{p\} \times (S^n \setminus \{ p\})$$
   which is a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb R^{n+1} \times \mathbb R^{n+1}$.
2. The tangent space $T_pS^n$ can be regarded as the orthogonal complement of $p$, i.e. as
   $$T_pS^n = \{x \in \mathbb R^{n+1} \mid x \cdot p = 0 \} .$$
   Then the "Euclidean" tangent bundle is
   $$TS^n = \bigcup_{p \in S^n} \{p\} \times T_pS^n = \{(p,x) \in \mathbb R^{n+1} \times \mathbb R^{n+1} \mid p \cdot p = 1, x \cdot p = 0 \} .$$
   It is well-known that this is a smooth submanifold of $R^{n+1} \times R^{n+1}$ which is diffeomorphic to the "abstract" tangent bundle of $S^n$.

Our task is to find diffeomorphisms $S^n \setminus \{ p\} \to T_pS^n$ which fit together to a diffeomorphism $S^n \times S^n \setminus \Delta \to TS^n$.

Stereographic projection from $p$ to $T_pS^n$ is the key (see [Stereographic projection when the "North/South Pole" is not given by $(0,...,\pm 1)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/454507)). This is given by
$$s_p : S^n \setminus \{ p\} \to T_pS^n, s_p(x) = \frac{x- (x \cdot p)p}{1 - x \cdot p} .$$

Let
$$\Omega = \{ (p,x) \in \mathbb R^{n+1} \times \mathbb R^{n+1} \mid x \cdot p \ne 1 \} .$$
This is an open subset of $\mathbb R^{n+1} \times \mathbb R^{n+1}$ which contains $S^n \times S^n \setminus \Delta$. Define
$$\phi : \Omega \to \mathbb R^{n+1} \times \mathbb R^{n+1}, \phi(p,x) = \left(p,\frac{x- (x \cdot p)p}{1 - x \cdot p}\right).$$
This is a smooth map such that $\phi(S^n \times S^n \setminus \Delta) = TS^n$. It restricts to a smooth map
$$\phi' : S^n \times S^n \setminus \Delta \to TS^n .$$

The inverse of $s_p$ is
$$s_p^{-1} : T_pS^n \to S^n \setminus \{ p\},s_p^{-1}(y) = \frac{(\lVert y \rVert^2 -1)p +2y }{\lVert y \rVert^2 +1} .$$
Define
$$\psi : \mathbb R^{n+1} \times \mathbb R^{n+1} \to  \mathbb R^{n+1} \times \mathbb R^{n+1}, \psi(p,y) = \left(p,\frac{(\lVert y \rVert^2 -1)p +2y }{\lVert y \rVert^2 +1} \right) .$$
This is a smooth map such that $\psi(TS^n) = S^n \times S^n \setminus \Delta$. It restricts to a smooth map
$$\psi'  : TS^n \to  S^n \times S^n \setminus \Delta .$$

By construction $\psi' \circ \phi' = id$ and $\phi' \circ \psi' = id$. Hence both maps are diffeomorphisms which are inverse to each other.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. Conceptually what I missed is that we can view $T\mathbb S^n$ as an embedded submanifold of $T\mathbb R^{n+1} \cong \mathbb R^{n+1} \times  \mathbb R^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

We have
\begin{align*} 
S^n \times S^n \setminus \Delta & = \left \{(x,y)\mid x, y \in S^n, x \neq y \right \} \\ &  = \bigcup_{x \in S^n} \left \{x\right \} \times (S^n \setminus \left \{x \right \}) \\ & \simeq \bigcup_{x \in S^n} \left \{-x \right \} \times T_{-x}S^n \\ & = TS^n 
\end{align*}
where the isomorphism $S^n \setminus \left \{x \right \} \simeq T_{-x}S^n$ is given by identifying $S^n \setminus \left \{x \right \}$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$ via the steoreographic projection where $x$ plays the role of $\infty$ and hence $-x$ plays the role of the origin, which is, the origin of the tangent space $T_{-x}S^n$.

Comment: Could you explain why the stereographic projection and the identification of $T_{-x} \mathbb S^n$ with $\mathbb R^n$ varies smoothly as we change $x$? It is clear to me that $\simeq$ above is a bijection, but I don't see why it is smooth.

Comment: The x suddenly changed to -x too, going from the second equality to the third. I don’t understand this solution.

Comment: @CraniumClamp Note that, viewed as subspaces of $\Bbb R^{n+1}$, $T_xS^n = T_{-x}S^n$.